# Edmonds-Karp bound doesn't seem to be tight

Tags: network-flow

The proof that the Edmonds-Karp algorithm will require at most $O(|V||E|)$ uses the fact that when an augmenting path has critical edge $(u, v)$, $\delta_f(u)$ strictly increases. Therefore, that particular edge can only be critical at most $|V|$ times and the total number of augmenting paths until the max flow is at most $|E| * O(|V|) = O(|V||E|)$.

But consider that vertex $u$ and all its outgoing edges. The sum of the times those outgoing edges are critical must be $O(|V|)$ by a similar reasoning. Couldn't we then take this fact and say the number of augmenting paths will be at most $|V| * O(|V|)$, by summing over the vertices (instead of summing over the edges like the textbook proof)? This would give $O(|V|^2)$ as the bound on the number of augmenting paths.

Put another way, consider the sum $\sum_{v \in v} \delta_f(v)$. This sum is at most $|V|^2$, but is strictly increased after every augmentation, so $O(|V|^2)$ augmentations will be required.

Is there any flaw in this reasoning? We know that $O(|V|^2|E|)$ is possible using Dinic's, but if Edmond's-Karp requires at most $O(|V|^2)$ augmentations we would get this same bound.

I tried searching for this and found [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/the-existing-bound-on-edmonds-karp-doesnt-seem-to-be-tight), but I do not understand the response or comment discussion. Maybe someone can rephrase it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two papers giving examples that show that the analysis of the Edmonds–Karp algorithm is tight:

- Norman Zadeh, [Theoretical efficiency of the Edmonds–Karp algorithm for computing maximal flows](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321679.321693).
- Zvi Galil, [On the theoretical efficiency of various network flow algorithms](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82671709.pdf).

Comment: Is there anything you can point me to that would show why my analysis is incorrect?

Comment: You can run your analysis on one of the tight examples and see where it goes wrong. You don’t need us for that.